# Backspace icon/representation

Tags: windows-phone-7, unicode, backspace

Is there a Unicode character for the backspace icon (as seen on some keyboards and on the Windows Phone soft keyboard)

[image: Windows Phone soft keyboard]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes: `\u232B` is the ["erase to the left" character](http://decodeunicode.org/en/u+232b): ⌫.

Comment: Indeed, but font support is relatively limited: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/232b/fontsupport.htm

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Thanks for the link. FWIW, Wingdings contains this character, too (0xD5).

Comment: Thanks. A pity that none of the fonts in Windows Phone are ones that support it.

Comment: Turns out this character is on Windows Phone (but maybe not in the fonts with Windows desktop)

Comment: But using old-time symbol fonts like Wingdings is a semantic nightmare.

Comment: Today, font support is much better. In Windows, the symbol is found in Arial Unicode MS and Segoe UI Symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Ansering on an old thread, but still relevant :). This is the exact same icon than the one used in the soft keyboard:

`<TextBlock Text="&#xE083;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" />`

Answer (score 1):

In case you are still looking for a solution.

Try this:

```
    char[] myunicodechar = { '\u232B'};
    myTextBlockLabel.Text = new string(myunicodechar);
```

Unfortunately it is not exactly the same symbol as the one you were looking for.

Comment: Thomas, that's essentially the same answer as Tim's.

Comment: That is true. But you wrote: "A pity that none of the fonts in Windows Phone are ones that support it." In this way you can use it and Windows Phone will display it.

Comment: Hey you're right! Just wrote a test app to confirm it. And I've found you can also include the unicode character in the XAML directly. So maybe the font as shipped in Windows Phone does include this character, but the ones in Windows don't.